How to reference a named range in formula from an external workbook
I've been trying to work this out but couldn't for some reason.
I have two excel files on Sharepoint in the same directory. One is called Data Array.xlsx which stores the data and another main workbook where we perform all tasks. In the main workbook I use the VLOOKUP function to search for the data in the other workbook. The below formula works well if I have the data workbook open but will generate a #REF! error if the data workbook is closed. I have searched many websites but couldn't find a solution.
=VLOOKUP(I35,'[Array Table.xlsx]PRODUCT MAPPING TABLE'!PRODUCT_TABLE,2,FALSE)
Array Table.xlsx is the data workbook, PRODUCT MAPPING TABLE is the first sheet and then PRODUCT_TABLE is the named range.
If data workbook is closed the formula autofills the full filepath and then the cell on main workbook containing the formula gives me the #REF! error.
=VLOOKUP(I35,'https://company.sharepoint.com/teams/filefoldersxxx/[Array Table.xlsx]PRODUCT MAPPING TABLE'!PRODUCT_TABLE,2,FALSE)
Any help is appreciated.
